# Is it possible to access builder properties before build() is called?

Tags: java, jax-rs, builder

So this might be a stupid question, but I'm new to Java, so please bear with me!

We're using ResponseBuilder to generate output as part of a REST service endpoint. I'm curious if it's possible to access the status property from within a different builder in the entity property, like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

Response response = Response
    .status(Status.NOT_FOUND) // this is the property I want
    .entity(Problem.builder()
         .withTitle("Test Error")
         .withStatus(Status.NOT_FOUND) // in here, instead of defining it again
         .withDetail("this is a test error")
         .build())
    .build();
```

What I really want to do is modify Problem.builder() so that I don't need to pass in a status at all, and it would grab the status that I set in Response.status automatically when no value is passed in.

But at this point, I can't pass in (or retrieve) the value to my Problem class.  I just need to know if it's even possible, and if so, how I would do it.

Thanks!

Comment: The question isn't stupid.  It's a valid question technically speaking.  But what practical reason would you have for needing this?  Maybe if we understood that, we could offer a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I have another builder that is going into that entity, and it also requires the status to be set.  I hate redundancy, so I'd like to call it in so I don't have to define it twice.

Comment: I wanted to play with this in my IDE, but I'm having trouble finding the particular Response class you're using.  I assume you've looked at the docs for the package you're using and that wasn't helpful.  Maybe you could provide the import statement for it.  What you can do is just call **Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)** and assign that to a variable of the appropriate type (ResponseBuilder?).  Then run your code in a debugger, and look at the resulting object and see if you can figure out what to grab out of it.

Comment: it's Jax-RS, I've added the imports.  I know I could assign Status.NOT_FOUND to a variable before either of the builders, but I'd still have to assign it twice, one for each builder. Ideally, I'd like to have Problem.builder() reference Response and grab the status out of it when I don't define it, but that is where I'm stuck... I don't know if I can get it at that point...

Comment: Strange.  My IDE won't resolve those imports. - Yeah, your use case makes sense.  Seems like either the docs or probing in a debugger would tell you.

Comment: Well, I think it could probably be any class with a builder pattern like that, right?

Comment: But even if the class implements a particular interface, and follows some pattern, it might have additional methods that could give you the information you're looking for.  If you want this to work on anything that implements a particular Builder interface, then you're absolutely stuck with just whatever methods that interface defines...by definition...right?

Comment: I mean that sounds right to me, but my Java experience is only a couple of months at this point, so that's why I'm here.  =]